# While loop not breaking?? C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, logical-or, logical-and

I'm trying to construct a simple dice game in C++. I do not understand why it's not breaking out of the while loop.

You are supposed to ONLY be able to bet 100, 300, or 500€.

Even if I enter my bet "100-300-500" which is supposed to be correct.  It still loops and says it's an invalid bet. Why doesn't it progress to the if statement when I have `if ((bet1 == 100) || (bet1 ==300) || (bet1==500))`

I've tried putting the if statement before the while loop and all sorts of things. I can't get it to work.

```
cout << "Please place a bet. 100, 300, 500kr" << endl;
cin >> bet1;

while ((bet1 <= 99) || (bet1 >= 101) || (bet1 <= 299) || (bet1 >= 301) || (bet1 <= 499) || (bet1 >= 501)) {
    cout << "Please place a valid bet" << endl;
    cin >> bet1;
}
if ((bet1 == 100) || (bet1 ==300) || (bet1==500)) {
    cout << "You have deposited " << " " << bet1 << "" << "And you now have: "<< saldo - bet1 << " " << "Remaining on your account." << endl;
}
```

Comment: can you tell a number that would make the while condition `false` ?

Comment: `(bet1 <= 99) || (bet1 >= 101) || (bet1 <= 299) || (bet1 >= 301) || (bet1 <= 499) || (bet1 >= 501)` this condition is always true

Comment: What @pptaszni commented. You'll have to group and combine those conditions differently.

Comment: You want to break the loop when the expression `bet1 == 100 || bet1 == 300 || bet1 == 500` becomes true. So loop while that condition is false, either by the logical negation `!` operator in front of the full condition (remembering parentheses around the condition), or using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) to reverse the logical expression.

Comment: I'm slightly curious about why you decided to write `(bet1 <= 99) || (bet1 >= 101)` rather than `bet1 != 100`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Well after reading here I am also quite curious on why I decided to do that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop

```
while ((bet1 <= 99) || (bet1 >= 101) || (bet1 <= 299) || (bet1 >= 301) || (bet1 <= 499) || (bet1 >= 501)) {
    cout << "Please place a valid bet" << endl;
    cin >> bet1;
}
```

is an infinite loop for any valid entered value 100, 300 or 500.

For example if the user will enter `100` then at least this condition `(bet1 <= 299)` evaluates to true. If the user will enter `300` then at least this condition `(bet1 >= 101)` evaluates to true. If the user will enter `500` then at least again this condition `(bet1 >= 101)` evaluates to true.

You should rewrite the while loop for example like

```
while ( bet1 != 100 && bet1 != 300 && bet1 != 500 )  {
    cout << "Please place a valid bet" << endl;
    cin >> bet1;
}
```

Using your approach to writing the loop the condition can look like

```
while ( ( bet1 <= 99 ) || ( bet1 >= 101 && bet1 <= 299 ) || (bet1 >= 301 && bet1 <= 499 ) || ( bet1 >= 501 ) ) {
    cout << "Please place a valid bet" << endl;
    cin >> bet1;
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for even including my pleb way of doing the loop :-)

Answer (score 2):

Any finite integer value is either `>=101` or `<=299`. Oring more conditions does not change that the condition is always `true`.

If you want to loop until `bet1` is either `100,300` or `500`:

```
while ( bet1 != 100 && bet1 != 300 && bet1 != 500) {...
```

Comment: Oh damn, didn't see your answer while I was writing the answer, sorry for the duplicate answer

Comment: @Rid no need to be sorry. There isnt much room for variation on the answer, but in general having complementary answers is a good thing

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the following:
Someone enters 100. Now the while-loop checks: <=99? no. >>Or<< maybe >=101? nope. >>Or<< <=299? It is! Therefore, the condition is true and it asks for a valid bet.

See how you can work it out from here.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition in the `while` loop is always `true`. You can check the valid number(s) in the following way:

```cpp
while (bet1 != 100 && bet1 != 300 && bet1 != 500)
{
    cout << "Please place a valid bet" << endl;
    cin >> bet1;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to check the bet after the loop; the loop doesn't exit with an invalid bet.

Comment: There, fixed! To be honest, I didn't pay much attention to the following code 

Answer (score 1):

Just this will always be true: (bet1 >= 101) || (bet1 <= 299)

ALL numbers on the number line are either >= 101 or <= 299

You need to use the logical AND (&&) operator e.g ((bet1 >= 101) && (bet1 <= 299)) || ((bet1 >= 301) && (bet1 <= 499))